# Flex 4 List - issues with drag and drop

Tags: list, drag-and-drop, flex4, itemrenderer

I have two different Spark `Lists`, with two different `ItemRenderers`, one of them with `dragEnabled="true"` and the other with `dropEnabled="true"`, in such a way that whenever I drag from one and drop in the other, a copy of the object dropped is created and inserted in the second List's dataProvider.

```
<s:List id="source"
        itemRenderer="componentsRenderers.SourceItemRenderer"
        dragEnabled="true"
        dataProvider="{elements}"/>

<s:List id="destination"
        itemRenderer="componentsRenderers.DestinationItemRenderer"
        dragEnabled="false"
        dropEnabled="true"
        change="destinationChanged(event)"/>
```

The event handler `destinationChanged()` is a method that parses the recently added object, removes it, and creates a new one that, among other stuff, has an `UIComponent` that has to be rendered.

The hole thing works well, except by one thing: as soon as the I load the application, the `UIComponent` of the first item to be dropped in `destination` never gets renderer. The full object is there and all the other functionalities related to it work, but the component doesn't get rendered. If I delete the object, making the List empty again, and insert it again, it gets rendered!

Also, after inserting the 'invisible' one, all the following inserts works.

Ideas?
Thanks!

---

**Update:** I just found out that the itemRenderer `DestinationItemRenderer` gets rendered twice for the first element to be dropped.

Comment: have a look here (http://saturnboy.com/2009/08/drag-and-drop-flex-4/), it may help

Comment: Maybe it won't help, because my problem isn't the drag and drop, because this is automatically handled by the List controls, but I'll have a look, thanks, Dan.